# Proving that the characteristic polynomial of this commutative linear transformation splits completely

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

T and S are linear transformations of a finite dimensional real vector space V with dimension 4, such that they commute. The minimal polynomial of S is $(t-1)^2(t-2)^2$

How do I prove that the characteristic polynomial $P_T (t)$ of T splits completely (factors into unique linear factors) and has at most two distinct roots?

Comment: By "splits completely" you mean $P_T(t) = (X-\alpha_1)\ldots (X-\alpha_n)$ with distinct $\alpha_i$ ?

Comment: Yup, that is indeed what I meant.

Comment: No, you probably don't mean that the $\alpha_i$ are distinct, since ohterwise $S=T$ is a counter-example.

Comment: In that case, $P_T$ has exactly $n$  distinct roots, and you need to prove it has at most $2$ distinct roots... weird

Comment: Screenshot of the question, from a past exam, in case I'm misinterpreting something to a large degree: http://prntscr.com/arhidp

Answer (score 0):

You can try to show that $S$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{pmatrix}$ where $A$ is the companion matrix of $(t-1)^2$ and $B$ is the companion matrix of $(t-2)^2$.

Then try to see what matrices commute with that.